# Print numbers from table

Tags: awk

How to get four numbers from this table please? The original input is much longer, so it is necessary to restricted the area.

Input:

```
chil           2   44843.084886752418        44843.080972494339       0.38261625919046571     

o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)
o 0  2 0 1 1  54002.864912732     0.000 = PERIASTRON EPOCH
o 0  3 0 1 1      0.086796671     0.000 = ECCENTRICITY
o 0  4 0 1 1    151.562809500     0.020 = PERIASTRON LONG.
o 0  5 0 1 1    107.927001263     0.053 = K1
o 0  6 0 1 1      0.418206121     0.000 = q = M2/M1,  K2 =  258.071309
o 0  7 0 1 1      0.004220000     0.000 = d omega/dt
o 0  8 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d P/dt
o 0  9 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d e/dt
o 0 10 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d K1/dt
o 0 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d q/dt

o 2  1 0 1 1  99000.000000000  1650.000 = PERIOD(2)
o 2  2 0 1 1  39254.892879388  -984.000 = PERIASTRON EPOCH
o 2  3 0 1 1      0.770000000     0.010 = ECCENTRICITY
o 2  4 0 1 1     68.284996369    -6.000 = PERIASTRON LONG.
```

Desired output

```
0.086796671
151.562809500
107.927001263
0.418206121
```

I unsuccessfully tried

```
/o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)/ { c=FNR;}
(FNR-c>=2 && c>0) {$2 ~ /\<0\>/ $3 ~ /\<3|4|5|6\>/ { print $7}
```

I want to say: If second column is 0 and the third colums is 3,4,5,6 print column 7

Comment: Please describe the rule.

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: But second column of your desired output are all `0`.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry

Comment: Sencond column value is same as arg of PERIOD? You want to restrict 2nd column as 0, and third column  as one of 3456, are there other rules?

Comment: Yes, arg of PERIOD is the number of 2nd column. The rules are exactly what you wrote. Plus I need to restrict the area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$2==0 && $3~/^[3456]$/{print $7}' data
```

**update**

Restrict to certain area:

```
awk '/o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD\(0\)/ {b=1}
     b && $2==0 && $3~/^[3456]$/{print $7}
     b && $3==6 { b=0 }' data
```

Comment: I didn't get anything

Comment: I use data copied from you question and get exactly your desired output.

Comment: There is a problem, that this is only a part od my file. It is much longer. How to add a restriction to this part. For instance with PERIOD(0) and PERIOD(2)?

Comment: Please elaborate your rule in your question.

Comment: I editted it in my question

Comment: See update, still think you should describe in more detail.

Comment: Thank you very very much, it works